# C-S-DEL (Kill an entire line at once) doesn't work in my emacs

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, iterm2

[This](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Killing-by-Lines.html) says that `C-S-DEL` is bound to `kill-whole-line` command that kills an entire line at once. I tried it on my macbook with emacs 24.5.1, however, it doesn't work at all. I then use `C-h k C-S-DEL` to check what happened when I press this hotkey. It says that, only `DEL` key is recognised other than `Ctrl + Shift + DEL`.

I install this emacs (version 24.5.1) via Homebrew and run it in iTerm2. It does't have a GUI version (I prefer to use in terminal), and is launched simply via `emacs` command.

How can I config my emacs to support `C-S-DEL`?

Comment: It's usually your terminal that fouls things up in these sorts of cases.  Do you run it in a GUI mode?

Comment: Which Emacs, invoked how? Acquamacs in a dedicated window is quite a different beast than `emacs -nw` in a Terminal window.

Comment: @tripleee I run emacs in iTerm2, it is installed via homebrew -- brew install emacs

Comment: @progo I run it in iTerm2

Comment: So which Emacs version do you end up with, and do you run it within the iTerm2 window, or as a background process in a separate window? Please [edit] the question instead of adding more comments. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shift key doesn't work in my emac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036378/shift-key-doesnt-work-in-my-emac)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but it is a bit cumberstone. Use a tool like Karibinder to remap `C-S-delete` while using your terminal to a key sequence your terminal does receive. You can use `M-x describe-unbound-keys` with [unbound.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/unbound.el) to find such keys. Then, within your emacs configuration, you should remap those keys to the appropriate functions.

Here is an example of how you could remap `C-S-delete` to `C-x n M-[ u` with Karibinder by putting it in your `private.xml` file. Karabinder's [documentation](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en) is very good.

```xml
  <appdef>
    <appname>TERMINAL</appname>
    <equal>com.apple.Terminal</equal>
  </appdef>

  <item>
    <name>Fix C-S-delete Emacs</name>
    <identifier>private.m_s_delete_emacs</identifier>
    <only>TERMINAL</only>
    <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
        KeyCode::DELETE, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L,
        KeyCode::X, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::N, KeyCode::BRACKET_LEFT, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L, KeyCode::U
    </autogen>
  </item>
```

And then in your emacs configuration:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x n M-[ u") 'kill-whole-line)
```

---

Perhaps there are more OS X users out there that prefer to use the terminal version of emacs over a GUI version. In that case, a comprehensive Karbiner & emacs configuration may be created by the community to cover all key sequences that use modifiers unsupported by the terminal. As of yet there is no such thing I believe, but I will update my answer if I find anything or if something is created.