# Shift key doesn't work in my emacs

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, terminal-emulator

I run emacs in gnome-terminal with `-nw` option, it works well except for some key shortcuts that include the <kbd>shift</kbd> key. For example, when I execute `C-M-S-v` (scroll-other-window-down), only `C-M-v` keys are recognised by Emacs which in turn scrolls the other window up.

I tried these key shortcuts in a GUI Emacs, everything works properly.

I guess there must be something wrong about the gnome-terminal or other terminal emulators, such as iTerm on Mac OS which I encountered the same problem.

How could I enable shortcuts that include shift key in a gnome-terminal?

Comment: A similar approach as what I described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026896/c-s-del-kill-an-entire-line-at-once-doesnt-work-in-my-emacs/34633762#34633762) will work for Ubuntu and other Linux distributions. You can use [XBK](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions?action=show&redirect=Howto%3A+Custom+keyboard+layout+definitions) to remap.

Answer (score 2):

The VT100 and terminals derived from it simply does not recognize the concept of a shifted control key.

Comment: Does it mean that there is no way to enable a shifted control key support?

Comment: Not straightforwardly, no.

Comment: Thx, it seems that I need to adapt emacs without shifted control key.

Comment: @tripleee Any reference for this as well as the genealogy of terminals?

Comment: @wlnirvana [ECMA-6](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-006.pdf) might be suitable as a starting point.  I don't have any link to a handy overview of the development of terminal devices but an old standard like that should at least implicitly tell you things about the capabilities of equipment from those days. (ECMA-6 is much older than VT100, which however retains some designs from earlier terminals for backwards compatibility ... I guess.)

Comment: Hmm... Is there any reason why the developers still do not support any shifted control key? (Or is there a good place to raise an feature request?) `Ctrl+Shift` works perfectly with Windows, but fails with all the Linux terminals I have used (built-in virtual console, urxvt, etc.)

Comment: I doubt it's possible to build a consensus to break backwards compatibility of an interface which exists for reasons of backwards compatibility in the first place. Don't use `-nw` if it's not what you want.

Comment: Of course, if you can find a legacy terminal which supported shifted control keys and your terminal software can emulate that, go for it. My knowledge of old hardware is limited so I don't know if such a thing ever existed.